# Networking between proxmox host and windows 7 real PC

Tags: networking, proxmox

Deploying working environment for business purposes I've installed proxmox. I've connected windows 7 to proxmox host directly without utilizing any switch or router. Windows 7 has access to the internet. Proxmox host does not have direct access to the internet. It could be connected through a router in the future to be accessed by its public IP.

I need to configure network between windows 7 and proxmox to be able to develop, deploy and run automated tests on VMs.

Network address with Internet access is: `192.168.1.0`
Network between proxmox and windows 7 is: `192.168.0.0`

Windows 7 is configured as a gateway in my case with IP address: `192.168.0.1`

To get access to my home network I've reconfigured `/etc/network/interfaces.new` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface wlx70f11c0e99bd inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid MyHuaweiRouterSSID
    wpa-psk MySecret

auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet static
    address 192.168.0.21
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    bridge_ports enp0s25
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

After PC's rebooting the interfaces `enp0s25` and `vimbr0` are `UP` but I could not ping `192.168.0.1` - `Destination Host Unreachable`

So, I could not connect these two machines together. Please help me to consider what I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to connect these two PCs by changing network configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces.new`.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface wlx70f11c0e99bd inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid MyHuaweiRouterSSID
    wpa-psk MySecret

auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet static
    address 192.168.0.21
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

Edited.
After trying to bridge `vmbr0` with `enp0s25` adapter changing `bridge_ports enp0s25` to `bridge_ports enp0s25`, network failed to work. So on Windows PC I've created bridge with wi-fi adapter that looks into internet and ethernet adapter that looks at proxmox PC. I was trying different configurations with ip addresses, gateways and adapters but after that I've just reconfigured network on proxmox to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  192.168.1.21
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        gateway  192.168.1.1
        bridge-ports enp0s25
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

removing `enp0s25` configuration from config file at all. It resolved the issue. However, `ifconfig` shows:

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:23:24:0b:e0:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 546  bytes 153563 (149.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 375  bytes 161758 (157.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  memory 0xf0500000-f0520000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 18  bytes 1544 (1.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18  bytes 1544 (1.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::223:24ff:fe0b:e02e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:23:24:0b:e0:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 546  bytes 143735 (140.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 367  bytes 159292 (155.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@proxmox:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev vmbr0 onlink
192.168.1.0/24 dev vmbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.21
```